# Bootstrap JS not working on JSP for multiple deleteButtons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, bootstrap-modal

Sometimes only Jquery 2.2 works. if I comment it the delete confirmation button wont pop up. 3.1.1 not working it seems for this code.

w3schools and getBootstrap codes has been refered for this

The delete confirmation modal is popping up for only the first entry in the table i.e foreach loop.

Dont know why..

Please help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/manageBooks.js"></script>-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#deleteButton").click(function () {
                    $("#deleteModal").modal();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Manage Books</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">pmahend1</p>
            <h4>Add book from Google Books</h4>
            <form action="manageBooks" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="searchGoogleBook" />
                <input type="search" placeholder="Enter Title or Author" name="query" style="width: 450px"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search"/>
                <p style="color:red;"></p>
            </form>
            <div id="results"></div>
            <br>
            <div><a class="btn btn-default btn-info" href="manageBooks?action=addBookPage">Add Books Manually</a></div>
            <br>
            <h4 class="container">Book Details </h4>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="form-group" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Edition</th>
                        <th>Genre</th>
                        <th>ISBN10</th>
                        <th>ISBN13</th>
                        <th>Update</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Adultery</td>
                        <td>Paulo Coelho</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Fiction</td>
                        <td>1101874090</td>
                        <td>9781101874097</td>
                        <td><a href="manageBooks?action=editBookPage&bookId=6" role="button" class="btn btn-link">Edit</a></td>
                        <!--<td><a href="manageBooks?action=deleteBookPage&bookId=6">Delete</a></td>-->
                        <td>
                            <!--<div class="container">-->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                                    <form role="form" action="manageBooks" method="POST">

                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Parmanently</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>Are you sure about this ?</p>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteBook">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="bookId" value="6" />
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
                                            </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--</div>-->

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Twilight&#039;s Wrath</td>
                        <td>SnÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ¦bjÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ¶rn</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Fiction</td>
                        <td>1490735372</td>
                        <td>9781490735375</td>
                        <td><a href="manageBooks?action=editBookPage&bookId=7" role="button" class="btn btn-link">Edit</a></td>
                        <!--<td><a href="manageBooks?action=deleteBookPage&bookId=7">Delete</a></td>-->
                        <td>
                            <!--<div class="container">-->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                                    <form role="form" action="manageBooks" method="POST">

                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Parmanently</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>Are you sure about this ?</p>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteBook">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="bookId" value="7" />
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
                                            </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--</div>-->

                        </td>
                    </tr>

            </table>       
        </div>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed automatically. May be I had to restart TomCat server.

Comment: in `jsp` it did not actually requires `Tomcat` restart while in the case of `Servlet` it is must.

Comment: I dont what exactly was wrong. Nothing was changed at servlet side. Could be cache you think?